# Redirect an Iframe page tab running on wordpress

Tags: facebook

I wish to redirect an Iframe page tab running on wordpress to open a custom shopping cart tab.
 To put it simply I want to click a page menu tab named Products here-

http://facebook.com/halfpriceheaven  ( Tab is hidden for now)

When it is clicked I want the custom tab SHOP NOW page to open.

Can this be done and how please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect the user **within** the Facebook Page tab iframe, then depending on your website language you can easily achieve this. In PHP for instance: `header("Location: my_page.php");`

Otherwise, if you want to redirect the user to your website **outside** Facebook, you use something like:

```
<script>top.location.href="http://example.com/page.php"</script>
```

Comment: Thx for reply, not sure you understand my goal.

Comment: @shane: Then how about elaborating more about your goal? you want to change the default landing tab when someone lands on your Facebook page?

Comment: Ok, If you went to http://facebook.com/halfpriceheaven there is a menu tab far right called WALL. When that is clicked I want the Wall page to open in place of the Iframe, same thing if I had product tab it would open shop now in place of Iframe..

Comment: What URL would I use to achieve this? I have tried using ?V=app_ APPID

Comment: @shane: I can see your "shop now" tab. I really can't see the problem here or can't understand your question.

Comment: Ok I want to be able to have people use the tabs in the iframe page for navigation and NOT use the tabs on the left side of page. Is there a way to connect the tabs- wall and products so the corresponding pages open as if they were clicked from top left tabs?

Comment: You have answered this here- answered Feb 26 at 14:27 for someone else.
 Yes there's:

echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $page_tab_url . "'</script>");

This way is mentioned in the Facebook documentation in a couple of places.
But where would I insert this code in a wordpress installation?
 
thx

Comment: Hmmm, this way you need to manually copy the "wall" url ..etc and add them as links to something like:`<a href="WALL_URL_HERE" target="_top">Wall Tab</a>`. Notice the **target** attribute, this will tell the page to load on the parent (facebook) level. How to do this in Wordpress is another matter actually.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I will reply to you if I find an answer for WP